# in cocoa, what is a good way to guarantee that a block or task will run only once?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macruby

For example, I have searcher operations that run concurrently. The first one that finds a match should start an updater task that delivers matches to the gui. I want to guarantee that the updater is only started once -- but I want to do so in a way that adds the minimum of overhead to the searcher operations.

Edit: if possible I want to do this in macruby, which currently has no mapping for dispatch_once.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `dispatch_once`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this is not implemented in macruby (and not planned to be implemented), which is why I didn't find it. Perhaps I can make an obj-c class to do just that part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know macruby, but maybe you can think of a global flag. Use mutexes to guarantee that only one thread a time can access the variable. Before calling the updater, each thread should check the variable. If it's false, it sets the variable to true and calls the updater, otherwise just continue.